# Does a stack state in the visitor break the visitor pattern?

Tags: visitor-pattern

I need to process the AST of a language, and a visitor on the tree just solves it nice. however some features would require that I kept some kind of stack (the stack of known variables) in the visitors permanent context, that is extended and reduced as the visit progresses. Does it break the visitor pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visitors can accumulate information during their visits – in fact the Visit implementation is the addition state that might be required with complex operations (like when expression tree nodes are far away from each other and still need to be know of each other)…
So it is safe to say that you can store a state (even in the form of a stack) in the Visitor as long as you don’t store any kind of information on the processed/visited nodes themselves